# yarn install wont run on my project keeps telling me that it couldn't find the binary react-script start

Tags: reactjs, firebase, visual-studio-code, yarn-lock.json

[my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIUl2.jpg)
[the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yb3B.jpg)
all my scripts dont work it keeps throwing the same error everytime.

i have cloned the repo in a different location and reinstalled the dependencies but still yarn start wont run.
what could be the problem?

Comment: Please add the code and error messages as text to your questions (instead of posting links to images). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try running your project with this `yarn run start`  or just add react-scripts with yarn using this command `yarn add react-scripts` because maybe react-scripts is not installed for some reason

Comment: this dosen't work either

Comment: are you sure you in the right folder ?? try deleting node moduls and re-install them with yarn i or yarn add

Comment: also try with npm because npm creates package.lock.json file and yarn creates yarn.lock.json so what type of lock file you have?